# D3 chart refresh - execution sequence

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

EDIT: Hi Jesus I have changed the code as follows but now the charts do not load at all, with an error of "uncaught syntax error - unexpected string". I may have misinterpreted your suggestion. Can you help me correct the code below please.

UPDATED CODE:

```
function updateData(url, divid, complete) {
alert("Start for: "+divid);
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 30},
        width = 838 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()        
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(10);

    // Get the data again
    d3.json(url, function (error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {
        alert(d.max_energy);
            d.max_energy = +d.max_energy;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data again 
        x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.xaxis;
        }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.max_energy;
        })]);

        // Make the changes
        svg.selectAll(".bar") // change the bar
        .data(data) // Update the data within.
        // No `.enter()` and `.exit()` phase.
        .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.xaxis);
        })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.max_energy);
        })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
            return height - y(d.max_energy);
        })
        if (complete) {
            complete();
        };
    }); 

alert("End for: "+divid);

};
```

UPDATED FUNCTION CALL:

```
case "C120031":
    updateData( "/sma/sma-php/data.php?var=CDAY&id=C1200031", "#daychart", function() {
        updateData( "/sma/sma-php/data.php?var=CWEEK&id=C1200031", "#weekchart", function() {
            updateData( "/sma/sma-php/data.php?var=CMONTH&id=C1200031", "#monthchart", function() {
                updateData( "/sma/sma-php/data.php?var=CYEAR&id=C1200031", "#yearchart", fucntion() {
                    updateData( "/sma/sma-php/data.php?var=CLIFE&id=C1200031", "#lifechart" );
                });
            });
        });
    });
    break;
```

---

I have a page with 5 tabs, each has a D3 bar chart, individually pulled from a MySql database.I am only showing three in the code below to minimise the amount of text in this post.

I also have a selectable set of fields on the page so when the user clicks on one of the fields the charts should refresh with data pertinent to the selection. The charts are created via a JSON transfer of data from a server sided script.

The question is I cannot get the charts to "refresh", although I have no syntax error on execution. The strange thing though is when I add "alerts" throughout the code what I see is:

All query calls are executed sequentially as programmed, but the data is parsed back at the end of all queries executed in what seems one job lot... and so the charts do not get updated.

To explain better, my client side code:

```
function MenuSelect(divid){

switch(divid)
{
    case "C120031":

       alert("Calling Day");            <--------- alert message at start of main proc
       updateData( "/sma/sma-php/data.php?var=CDAY&id=C1200031", "#daychart" );

       alert("Calling Week");
       updateData( "/sma/sma-php/data.php?var=CWEEK&id=C1200031", "#weekchart" );

       alert("Calling Month");
       updateData( "/sma/sma-php/data.php?var=CMONTH&id=C1200031", "#monthchart" );

    break;

    case "C120048":
... MANY OTHER INSTANCES HERE ...
    break;

    default:
    };
};

function updateData(url, divid) {

alert("Start for: "+divid);             <--------- alert message at start of sub proc

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 30},
        width = 838 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(10);

    // Get the data again
    d3.json(url, function (error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {

            alert(d.max_energy);  <--------- alert message listing raw data 

            d.max_energy = +d.max_energy;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data again 
        x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.xaxis;
        }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.max_energy;
        })]);

        // Make the changes
        svg.selectAll(".bar") // change the bar
        .data(data) // Update the data within.
        // No `.enter()` and `.exit()` phase.
        .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.xaxis);
        })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.max_energy);
        })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
            return height - y(d.max_energy);
        })
    }); 

alert("End for: "+divid);              <--------- alert message at end of sub proc

};
```

The way this reports back during execution is:

First it shows entering and exiting "updateData" function as below.

```
"Calling Day"
"Start for #daychart"
"End for #daychart"
"Calling Week"
"Start for #weekchart"
"End for #weekchart"
"Calling Month"
"Start for #monthchart"
"End for #monthchart"
```

The it lists all data for each of the query runs, sequentially per below.

```
"0.000"
"1.345"
"1.679"
```

This is telling me the execution of "updateData" does not wait to complete (that is it does not wait to get the response from the server) before it moves on to the next execution of "updateData".

What am I missing? I need to code to execute sequentially and wait for the server response before moving to the next execution.

As an aside, if I get the code to execute only one instance of "updateData" it works in a similar way, whereby the start and finish alerts happen before it displays the alerts with the data.

Interestingly upon page first load data is pulled from MySQL using the same server side procedure (data.php) and loaded into a "create chart" D3 js, and it works perfectly and sequentially. Maybe my "updateData" procedure is coded wrong? I am not receiving any syntax errors in inspect/console though...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code looks OK. I noticed you have a typo in the last updateData function definition: it reads 'fucntion'.

Answer (score 0):

d3.json executes asynchronously. That is, the updateData call will return and continue with the next call before d3.json has completed. In order to fix this, you can pass a callback to the updateData function and chain subsequent calls:

```
updateData("", "", function() {
    updateData("", "", function() {
        updateData("", "");
     });
});

updateData(url, vivid, complete) {
    d3.json(.., function(...) {
        //all other code 
        if (complete) {
            complete();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Jesus, many thanks for the reply!! I understand what you suggest but I am stuck with how I have added to my code. Also, how come there is no async issue on page load / chart creation? I have added my code changes above. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jesus, thanks again! I am now getting "complete is not defined". I need to define complete. can you point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Well, it all looks good. Given you have the `if(complete) { complete();  }` test you shouldn't be getting complete not defined. What line are you getting that error from?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out from further investigation that the sequencing of data coming from the code execution is correct. I had a different problem as to why it was not working, as the code to redraw the chart is in the D3.json callback function... the problem has now evolved to not being able to transition the axis nor place the value labels on the bars. The bar chart data is transitioning OK. [I have a jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/h8Rsg/) demonstrating the issue. Muchas gracias!

```
// Get the data again
//      d3.json("http://10.0.0.13/sma/sma-php/inverterdata.php?var=PDAY&id=P100023", function (error, data) {
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.max_energy = +d.max_energy;
});

// Scale the range of the data again 
x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    console.log(d.xaxis);
    return d.xaxis;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.max_energy;
})]);

// Make the changes
svg.selectAll(".bar") // change the bar
.data(data) // Update the data within.
.transition().delay(function (d, i) {
    return i / data.length * 1000;
})
    .duration(500)
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.xaxis);
})
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(d.max_energy);
})
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function (d) {
    return height - y(d.max_energy);
});

//Update all labels
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data).transition()
    .delay(function (d, i) {
    return i / data.length * 1000;
})
    .duration(500)
    .text(function (d) {
    return parseFloat(Math.round(d.max_energy * 100) / 100).toFixed(1);
})
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
    return x(i) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
})
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return height - y(d.max_energy) + 24;
});

//});
```